# What does six dots mean in variadic templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, partial-specialization

The following are *some* partial specializations for `std::is_function` from libstdc++'s `<type_traits>`:

```
  /// is_function
  template<typename>
    struct is_function
    : public false_type { };

  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>
    : public true_type { };

  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes...) &>
    : public true_type { };

  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes...) &&>
    : public true_type { };

  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes......)>
    : public true_type { };

  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes......) &>
    : public true_type { };

  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes......) &&>
    : public true_type { };
```

What exactly do the last three partial specializations mean, and how are they different from the first three? I tried searching for `......` in C++14 specification, but failed to find anything helpful.

Comment: A narrower version of this question would focus on why `is_function` requires these specializations(*which I cover*) and how do they work. This would differentiate it from the proposed duplicate which focuses solely on is this valid syntax.